# Tesseract Giving NoSuchFieldException in some Android Devices

Tags: android, tesseract

My android app uses Tesseract version 3.0.1 and currently the app is working properly on most of the devices **except** some Samsung devices specially those running android Lollipop.

The exception which is occurring is:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "J" field "mNativeData" in class "Lcom/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI;" or its superclasses
at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.nativeClassInit(Native Method)
at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at aj.colorise.g.a(Unknown Source)
at aj.colorise.p.a(Unknown Source)
at aj.colorise.p.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
```

Why is this?
I have configured my ProGuard to not include Tesseract project and made a rules file with the content:

```
  -dontoptimize
  -dontobfuscate
  -dontpreverify
  -dontshrink
  -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
  -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
  -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
  -dontnote
```

Comment: How did you include the library? It looks like you're using a library that doesn't match your binaries.

Comment: I dont remember exactly...I had an old version of tessdata which was roughly 17-18 mb and i replaced it with newer version of size 9mb. I directly copy pasted it in the directory. Nothing else